# Update SelectedItem when Navigating a ListCollectionView

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, listbox

I have a ListCOllectionView which is binded to a Listbox. When I click on it I can select a Item. Now I want to be able to go to the previous and next item in the Listbox and have it at the same time Selected.

My Listbox

```
<ListBox x:Name="Imported_images" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedImage}" ItemsSource="{Binding SortedImageLibrary}"/>

<Button x:Name="next" Command="{Binding NextImageCommand}" >
<Button x:Name="previous" Command="{Binding PreviousImageCommand}">
```

ViewModel

```
private ListCollectionView _sortedImageLibrary;
public ListCollectionView SortedImageLibrary
{
    get
    {
        if (_sortedImageLibrary == null) 
        {
            _sortedImageLibrary = new ListCollectionView(ImageLibrary);
            _sortedImageLibrary.IsLiveSorting = true;
            _sortedImageLibrary.CustomSort = new ImageComparer();                     
         }
        return _sortedImageLibrary; 
    }
    set
    {
        _sortedImageLibrary = value; RaisePropertyChanged();
    }
}

private Image _selectedImage;
public Image SelectedImage   
{
    get { return _selectedImage; }
    set { _selectedImage = value; RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedImage"); }
}

public RelayCommand NextImageCommand { get; set; }
public RelayCommand PreviousImageCommand { get; set; }
public void PreviousImageExecute()
{
    if (SortedImageLibrary.CurrentPosition == 0)
    {
    }
    else
    {
        SortedImageLibrary.MoveCurrentToPrevious();
    }
}
public void NextImageExecute()
{
    if (SortedImageLibrary.CurrentPosition == SortedImageLibrary.Count - 1)
    {
    }
    else
    {
        SortedImageLibrary.MoveCurrentToNext();
    }
}
```

I can go to the next and previous item in the ListCollectionView, but the SelectedImage doesn't update. How Can I update the Selected Image as I navigate through the ListCollectionView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need to set the instance of the `SelectedImage` property on navigation. The PropertyChangedEvent should trigger the update on WPF side.

I am not sure but I guess it should look similar to something like this:

```
public void PreviousImageExecute()
{
    if (SortedImageLibrary.CurrentPosition == 0)
    {
    }
    else
    {
        SortedImageLibrary.MoveCurrentToPrevious();
    }
    SelectedImage = SortedImageLibrary.CurrentItem as Image;
}
public void NextImageExecute()
{
    if (SortedImageLibrary.CurrentPosition == SortedImageLibrary.Count - 1)
    {
    }
    else
    {
        SortedImageLibrary.MoveCurrentToNext();
    }
    SelectedImage = SortedImageLibrary.CurrentItem as Image;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After you navigate, you should assign the CurrentItem to the SelectedImage property. Of course yo need to evaluate if your navigation method returns true before your assignment.